# How to Uniquely Identify HTML Elements without IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Currently working on an issue where I need to be able to quickly, and accurately identify each element within an HTML DOM. The problem is that I do not have the ability to interact with any of the server side or client side javascript, so I cannot simply add IDs to elements. The site can also be dynamic (like a react app) so elements may be added/removed/moved throughout the session, making this quite difficult. I am able to add scripts on top of the app, but not modify what is already there.

I thought using some combination of XPath and HTML attributes would work, but overall the solution seems very messy, and not 100% accurate. For example, in the HTML snippet below, it is not possible (to my knowledge) to uniquely identify the `div` elements in the tree.

```html
<head>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
</head>
```

An XPath search of `"/head/div"` would return both `div`s, and since they have no attributes, there is no way to uniquely identify one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use a `<div>` inside the `<head>` tag.

I suggest using a selector like [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for picking the dom element you want to.

Here's an example using your code:

```html
const mySecondDiv = document.querySelector('head div:nth-child(2)')
```

As long as you don't have control of how and when the markup changes, your selector could become obsolete/invalid fast. I should say that whatever solution you have will depend on the markup, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This solution does actually help a lot, and I should have read more about XPaths before asking. However, one thing this doesn't address is the issue with the page being dynamic. If the element were to move at all, the XPath is no longer correct, and I'm not sure how to account for that.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't account the content change. You'll need to change your script whenever the content changes.